# What spell or item works like a Field Radio or closest equivalent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The question I am hoping to find the answer to is what could be used to replicate the functionality of a broadcast radio, where it can send a message near instantaneously over distances of miles. The message may be as simple as a single bit of information, but sent clearly and instantly. Not Whispering Wind which goes slower than simply sending a runner.
Preferably two way communication. Preferably a magic item that can be given to NPCs to be used with minimal levels investment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind.

- Although not a spell you could implement a version of Sending Stones, they are in 5e but I thought they were in PF somewhere as well coming from 3.X. Pretty much exactly a two-way radio.
- Telepathic Bond. Connects a number of people upon casting. Has the added benefit of being silent once utilized and so long as you are on the same plane has unlimited range once cast.

Comment: Telepathic bond seems to be excellent value if combined with permanency, 12.5k for infinite use and range, plus it cannot be claimed as "loot" by the PCs. In fact, they may have no idea it's even there...

Answer (score 8):

You may be looking for the spell [Sending](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sending), which allows instant, two-way (but limited) communication between any two creatures that know each other and are on the same plane. It's spell level 4 minimum, so a Magic Item version should be affordable. Most other spells I found don't reach the "miles" of distance.

Comment: Oh that is awesome, so if the Big Bad ever became "familiar" with the PCs then the main villain of the game can send them taunting messages and my players can even reply back. Wouldn't even need a magic item (which would be too expensive) it keeps the Big Bad relevant throughout the plot without being a constant imminent threat.

Answer (score 7):

While whispering wind itself takes time, the [missive stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/stone-missive), a magic item based on it, allows person-to-person messaging instantaneously ($10k, 3 mi. range). The new [communique rings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/communique-rings) from Ultimate Intrigue are cheaper but have less range ($6k, 1 mi. range).

Comment: Missive Stones would be a great plot device, it's something the PCs may pick up to have a 1-to-1 with the big bad "Khan, you've got the MacGuffin but you don't have me. You're going to have to come down here and get me!" plus  it's going to be bound by relevance as you know they'd have to be quite close to reply, within 3 miles.